# How to configure network printer HP Colorlaserjet M281fdw on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, scanner

I failed to install network printer for HP Colorlaserjet M281fdw on ubuntu 20.04.
The information:

- hplip version: 3.20.3
- hplip, hplip-data, hplip-gui were installed
- hp plugin was installed (USB printer and scanner were installed succesffuly)
- The printer and computer is the same network.the ip of printer is alive on the network (can ping to printer's ip)
- I failed to detect the network printer by hp-setup. Both in automatic or manually (input printer's ip in advance mode)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: isn't that model of printer WiFi?

Comment: Have you read https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting ?

Comment: I tried to find network printer with "lpinfor -v". Added the uri with lpadmin. But i'm not successful and got the same problem with ipp and dnssd: Operation now in progress.

Comment: @24601 This printer is network and wifi printer. It's working well on the windows

Comment: The problem's solved. I had to remove firewall on the printer, and it's working well now. Thank again for your views.